# shell script throws error only when run in Python script

Tags: python, shell, arduino, subprocess, os.system

I made a python client for Arduino firmware update automation.

All the other parts work just fine, but one shell script does not.
Since compile of the `.ino` file should be done with the external program(arduino-cli), I have the python script execute a shell script. It is simple shell scrip with only three-line, and I have checked it works just fine with the native(?) shell. However, when I try to run them by Python, one line keeps throwing an error.

Here is the shell script making a problem.

```
arduino-cli compile --fqbn per1234:sam:arduino_due_x_dbg ./arduino/firmware/firmware.ino
```

This supposed to be work like below,

```
Sketch uses 21764 bytes (4%) of program storage space. Maximum is 524288 bytes.

Atmel SMART device 0x285e0a60 found
Erase flash
done in 0.037 seconds
```

but throwing errors like below.

```
/tmp/arduino-sketch-511175B80FD16B46B3F1B7254ACB214D/../arduino-core-cache/core_per1234_sam_arduino_due_x_dbg_4272af91dc8ee9796d1aff864e3842a4.a(main.cpp.o): In function `main':
/home/ubuntu/.arduino15/packages/per1234/hardware/sam/1.6.11-arm64/cores/arduino/main.cpp:57: undefined reference to `setup'
/home/ubuntu/.arduino15/packages/per1234/hardware/sam/1.6.11-arm64/cores/arduino/main.cpp:61: undefined reference to `loop'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have tried to run the line with `os.system()` and  `subprocess.call()`, but no fun with both methods. They make exactly the same result.

Here's the way how I tried.

```
os.system("arduino-cli compile --fqbn per1234:sam:arduino_due_x_dbg ./arduino/firmware/firmware.ino")

#and

subprocess.call(['arduino-cli', 'compile', '--fqbn', 'per1234:sam:arduino_due_x_dbg', './arduino/firmware/firmware.ino'])
```

I am running this code on RPi4, Ubuntu 20.04 server with Python 3.8.5.

Any advice would be appreciated.

*ADD - ENV Variables
Native

```
declare -x COLORTERM="truecolor"
declare -x DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus"
declare -x GIT_ASKPASS="/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/f30a9b73e8ffc278e71575118b6bf568f04587c8/extensions/git/dist/askpass.sh"
declare -x HOME="/home/ubuntu"
declare -x LANG="C.UTF-8"
declare -x LESSCLOSE="/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s"
declare -x LESSOPEN="| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s"
declare -x LOGNAME="ubuntu"
declare -x LS_COLORS="rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:"
declare -x MOTD_SHOWN="pam"
declare -x OLDPWD="/home/ubuntu"
declare -x PATH="/home/ubuntu/asperitas-client/venv/bin:/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/f30a9b73e8ffc278e71575118b6bf568f04587c8/bin:/home/ubuntu/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
declare -x PS1="(venv) \\[\\e]0;\\u@\\h: \\w\\a\\]\${debian_chroot:+(\$debian_chroot)}\\[\\033[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\[\\033[00m\\]:\\[\\033[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033[00m\\]\\\$ "
declare -x PWD="/home/ubuntu/asperitas-client"
declare -x SHELL="/bin/bash"
declare -x SHLVL="2"
declare -x SSH_CLIENT="###.###.###.### 57125 22"
declare -x SSH_CONNECTION="###.###.###.### 57125 ###.###.###.### 22"
declare -x TERM="xterm-256color"
declare -x TERM_PROGRAM="vscode"
declare -x TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION="1.54.1"
declare -x USER="ubuntu"
declare -x VIRTUAL_ENV="/home/ubuntu/asperitas-client/venv"
declare -x VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_MAIN="/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/f30a9b73e8ffc278e71575118b6bf568f04587c8/extensions/git/dist/askpass-main.js"
declare -x VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE="/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/f30a9b73e8ffc278e71575118b6bf568f04587c8/node"
declare -x VSCODE_GIT_IPC_HANDLE="/run/user/1000/vscode-git-ef1c3daaf1.sock"
declare -x VSCODE_IPC_HOOK_CLI="/run/user/1000/vscode-ipc-1b326fa4-d803-4d45-94c8-2575754eed33.sock"
declare -x XDG_DATA_DIRS="/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop"
declare -x XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_CLASS="user"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_ID="1"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_TYPE="tty"
```

Python (`subprocess.call('export', shell=Ture)`)

```
export COLORTERM='truecolor'
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS='unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
export GIT_ASKPASS='/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/f30a9b73e8ffc278e71575118b6bf568f04587c8/extensions/git/dist/askpass.sh'
export HOME='/home/ubuntu'
export LANG='C.UTF-8'
export LESSCLOSE='/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
export LESSOPEN='| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
export LOGNAME='ubuntu'
export LS_COLORS='rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
export MOTD_SHOWN='pam'
export OLDPWD='/home/ubuntu'
export PATH='/home/ubuntu/asperitas-client/venv/bin:/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/f30a9b73e8ffc278e71575118b6bf568f04587c8/bin:/home/ubuntu/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
export PS1='(venv) \[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
export PWD='/home/ubuntu/asperitas-client'
export SHELL='/bin/bash'
export SHLVL='2'
export SSH_CLIENT='###.###.###.### 57125 22'
export SSH_CONNECTION='###.###.###.### 57125 ###.###.###.### 22'
export TERM='xterm-256color'
export TERM_PROGRAM='vscode'
export TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION='1.54.1'
export USER='ubuntu'
export VIRTUAL_ENV='/home/ubuntu/asperitas-client/venv'
export VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_MAIN='/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/f30a9b73e8ffc278e71575118b6bf568f04587c8/extensions/git/dist/askpass-main.js'
export VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE='/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/f30a9b73e8ffc278e71575118b6bf568f04587c8/node'
export VSCODE_GIT_IPC_HANDLE='/run/user/1000/vscode-git-ef1c3daaf1.sock'
export VSCODE_IPC_HOOK_CLI='/run/user/1000/vscode-ipc-1b326fa4-d803-4d45-94c8-2575754eed33.sock'
export XDG_DATA_DIRS='/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR='/run/user/1000'
export XDG_SESSION_CLASS='user'
export XDG_SESSION_ID='1'
export XDG_SESSION_TYPE='tty'
export _='/home/ubuntu/asperitas-client/venv/bin/python3'
```

When I compared them, there are four differences.

1. "" and ''
2. // and /
3. The last line if Python is additional to the native one
4. `export` and `declare -x`

of course, the user is the same. Still have no clue :(

Comment: Are there any environment variables that `arduino-cli` uses while compiling? It's possible that when you are calling the command through Python those env vars are not being injected.

Comment: Try adding the argument `shell=True` to `call` function.

Comment: @Shiva Thank you for the advice. Not sure about that how can I check that? Should I just try export??

Comment: I am not even an arduino beginner :) I assume there's an equivalent of `.bashrc` where you store env vars.

Comment: @Shiva Thank you again. I’ll try them out.

Comment: Do try the `shell=True` argument in `subprocess.call` function. It's equivalent to running the command through shell(and not through Python). So, automatically it will include env vars of the shell.

Comment: @Shiva Unfortunately, no fun again. The same error happens. :(

Comment: Since the complaint is about the C code, why haven't you shown us the C code?  You may have different C compilers.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for your attention. Could you explain a bit more about that? You want to see the .ino code? or the compiler?

Comment: Well, the basic complaint is that you're getting C++ compilation errors in `main.cpp`.  I assume that must be your code, unless it's being generated.  What's in your .ino?